# How to calculate sqrtPriceX96 in solidity?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

The uniswap docs commonly mention sqrtPriceX96:

`A Fixed point Q64.96 number representing the sqrt of the ratio of the two assets (token1/token0)`

Calculate in JS:
https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/blob/2c8aa3a653831c6b9e842e810f5394a5b5ed937f/src/utils/encodeSqrtRatioX96.ts

how to calculate sqrtPriceX96 in solidity?

`uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = ???;`

Comment: Calculate from what?

Comment: @kfx I create pool. `NonfungiblePositionManager(payable(Manager)) .createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary( address(MY_TOKEN), wMaticAddress, 3000, sqrtPriceX96 );`

Comment: If you create a pool, you need to pass the initial price as the argument. Assuming you know what initial price you want, the easiest way would be to calculate the `sqrtPriceX96` offline and pass that as a constant in Solidity code. Otherwise look at the SqrtPriceMath library for some examples how do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

What variables are available to you? The easiest way is just to ask Uniswap V3 what the current sqrtPriceX96 is.

Comment: I create pool. `NonfungiblePositionManager(payable(Manager)) .createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary( address(MY_TOKEN), wMaticAddress, 3000, sqrtPriceX96 );` and `sqrtPriceX96`?

Comment: kfx has a good answer, the easiest way is just to pass it from offline

Answer (score 0):

This should work with all decimals:

```
function getPrice(uint160 sqrtRatioX96, uint dec0, uint dec1)
external
pure
returns (uint256 price)
{
uint256 dec = dec1<=dec0 ? (18-dec1)+dec0 :dec0;
uint256 numerator1 =uint256(sqrtRatioX96) *uint256(sqrtRatioX96);  
uint256 numerator2 =10**dec; 
price = FullMath.mulDiv(numerator1, numerator2, 1 << 192);
}
```

Comment: He is asking how to get sqrtPriceX96 and you have that in the parameters of function, this is wrong

Answer (score -1):

This way:

```
const sqrtPriceToPrice = (sqrtPriceX96, token0Decimals, token1Decimals) => {
    let mathPrice = Number(sqrtPriceX96) ** 2 / 2 ** 192;
    const decimalAdjustment = 10 ** (token0Decimals - token1Decimals);
    const price = mathPrice * decimalAdjustment;
    return price;
};
```

Comment: He is asking how to get sqrtPriceX96 and you have that in the parameters of function, this is wrong